# Allowing a Devise / OmniAuth-Facebook user to complete their registration on user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

In Rails 4, I am trying to figure out how to best redirect a Devise user after a successful OmniAuth Facebook login.

When a user logs in to my app for the first time with OmniAuth-Facebook, I have to set some variables (such as username) in their user model to some default, but I want the user to confirm or change these default.  For example, if there is a Facebook "nickname", I will use that to set their required username in their user model, or First Name + Last Name if no nickname is available.

If the user is logging in for the first time with Facebook, I've just created their user model in the database, and I want to redirect them to the account editing page, with a flash message saying something to the effect of "Update your account to complete your registration".  If the user has logged in previously, I'll assume they've already been informed about their default username and are aware of it, so I will just redirect them to their default destination.

I gather that this is the typical starting point:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook    
        # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
        @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
            set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
        else
            session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end
end
```

I know that I can override after_sign_in_path_for, but it doesn't know the result of my call to User.find_for_facebook_oauth.  If I knew that a new user was created by User.find_for_facebook_oauth, I could redirect them to the account editing page (via an overridden after_sign_in_path_for method) so they could review any defaults and make changes.  I know that I can solve this problem by putting a flag in the database schema for the user model, but this seems like overkill.  For example, I could add a new database field for "is_new_user", which would be enabled when User.find_for_facebook_oauth saves a new user, which is read by after_sign_in_path_for, and disabled whenever the account editing page is viewed.  I don't like this approach and would prefer it if after_sign_in_path_for knew what happened during the current omniauth request, and act accordingly.  There's no need for me to add a field to the database.

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: you can use with `:sign_in_count` column. if this is 0 it means user has not sign in before / the first time of login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @anonymousxxx, the solution is simple.  Devise already added the :sign_in_count column to my User model, so referencing that gives me all the information I need!